# VS 2012 LINQ to XML XmlDocument.Descendants causes "Try specifying type arguments explicitly"

Tags: xml, linq

I am making a simple LINQ Query against an XmlDocument and I get the "Try specifying type arguments explicitly" error.  Here is my C# code:

```
var Document = new XmlDocument();
Document.LoadXml(XmlFilePath);
var selectedMessage = from msg in Document.Descendants("Messages").Descendants("Message")
                      where msg.Attribute("Code").Value == constant
                      select msg;
```

The xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MessageService>
   <Messages>
     <Message Code="DE-01003" Section="Delphi Backend" Line="N/A" Claim="No" Constant="E_PHY_LN_INV_HCPCS" Description="Error reading HCPCS code on line %d (%s)" />
     <Message Code="DE-01004" Section="Delphi Backend" Line="N/A" Claim="No" Constant="E_PHY_LN_RBRVS_FAMILY_INV_DT" Description="RunFamilyReduction: Invalid Date on claim line %d (%s)" />
     <Message Code="DE-02002" Section="Delphi Backend" Line="N/A" Claim="No" Constant="E_AMB_LN_INV_HCPCS" Description="Invalid or missing HCPCS code on claim line %d (%s)" />
     .
     .
     .
   </Messages>
</MessageService>
```

The first call to .Descendants causes the error.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Susan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `XmlDocument`, but attempting to use a `Descendants` method... and I *expect* you're thinking of [`XDocument.Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx).

Is there any reason you *want* to use `XmlDocument` instead of LINQ to XML? Mixing and matching isn't going to be ideal...

Just change the first couple of lines to:

```
// Variable name casing changed to be more idiomatic
var document = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

Comment: Can I load and external Xml document into an XDocument?   I didn't think so.  I thought I had to start with an XmlDocument.

Comment: Document is actually a property in a subclass I just simplified it for the example.  And XDocument does not have a Load Method.

Comment: @user1818345: Yes, absolutely. You don't need to use XmlDocument at all.

Comment: @user1818345: Um, yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx

Comment: It is static Duh on my part!